# Backup NAS to another NAS?

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage, connection, copy

is there a way to backup / transfer a NAS (it's like a big harddrive with some access to a webinterface, but closed linux etc.... only two ethernet ports) to another one? or is the only way to connect both NASs to my computer and copy the data from one to the other?

it's like 750gb of data...

thanks in advance...

regards

Comment: What brand and model is your NAS?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the NAS.  Many [QNAP](http://www.qnap.com) devices support this natively, for example.  I'm not sure about other brands or NAS software implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Synology has alot of backup options including backing up to other Synology NAS's, Any other rsync capable server or Amazon Glacier.

http://www.synology.com/dsm/dsm_app.php?lang=us